# My SQL stored procedure with an update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that is used when a new transaction is inserted. This procedure inserts properly into the transactions table, but I also need to update another related table based on inserted values.

Based on the Product_ID I need to update PT_Pct_to_Salon in a table called 'Salon' with a value from a table called 'Zen_Products_Description'.  The related salon can be found using the 'Salon_ID' from insert which is equivalent to the 'Salon' table's PK ID.

The value I need to insert is in the 'web_share' field of the 'Zen_Products_Description' table.  The related row in 'Zen_Products_Description' can be matched by matching the inserted value 'Product_ID' with the PK of 'Zen_Products_Description' which is called 'products_id'.

I am using MySQL 5.

---

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Transactions
(Cart_Trans_ID, Customer_ID, Pass_Through_Amt, Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Qty, Salon_ID,  Stylist_ID, Trans_Type, customerAddress, customerCity, customerEmail, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPhone, customerPostal, customerState) 
VALUES (Cart_Trans_ID, Customer_ID, Pass_Through_Amt, Product_ID, Product_Name, Product_Qty, Salon_ID, Stylist_ID, Trans_Type, customerAddress, customerCity, customerEmail, customerFirstName, customerLastName, customerPhone, customerPostal, customerState);
Insert Into Zen_Products_Description
(products_id, products_name) 
Values (Product_ID, Product_Name) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
products_name = Product_Name;

//this is where I try unsuccessfully to update
update Salon
set PT_Pct_to_Salon = Zen_Products_Description.web_share
join Salon
on Salon.Salon_ID = Transactions.Salon_ID
join Zen_Products_Description
on Zen_Products_Description.products_id = Transactions.Product_ID;

END
```

---

Answer (score 1):

lol - you forgot to ask a question...  be succinct and i'll help you

```
BEGIN 
  INSERT INTO Transactions 
    (Cart_Trans_ID, Customer_ID, 
     Pass_Through_Amt, Product_ID, Product_Name, 
     Product_Qty, Salon_ID, Stylist_ID, 
     Trans_Type, customerAddress, customerCity, 
     customerEmail, customerFirstName, customerLastName, 
     customerPhone, customerPostal, customerState) 
  VALUES 
    (Cart_Trans_ID, Customer_ID, 
     Pass_Through_Amt, Product_ID, Product_Name, 
     Product_Qty, Salon_ID, Stylist_ID, 
     Trans_Type, customerAddress, customerCity, 
     customerEmail, customerFirstName, customerLastName, 
     customerPhone, customerPostal, customerState); 


Insert Into Zen_Products_Description 
  (products_id, products_name) 
Values 
  (Product_ID, Product_Name) 

ON DUPLICATE KEY 

UPDATE products_name = Product_Name
```

########## everything above here is immaterial

```
update Salon 
  set PT_Pct_to_Salon = Zen_Products_Description.web_share 
join Salon on Salon.Salon_ID = Transactions.Salon_ID 
join Zen_Products_Description 
  on Zen_Products_Description.products_id = Transactions.Product_ID;

############### here is update

UPDATE salon A 
INNER JOIN Transactions B ON A.salon_ID = B.salon_ID
INNER JOIN Zen_Products_Description C on C.Products_id = B.product_id
SET A.PT_Pct_to_Salon = C.web_share
```

##  , a.x = b.x etc...

## and by the way - learn how to format your code so people can read it...

```
END
```

Comment: This should really be a comment on the question.